# NullPointerException from using getFileStreamPath on a non-null context?

Tags: java, android

currently working on an app for myself and ran into this issue, my context is clearly not null (would exit the function otherwise). I'm an android noobie so unsure what to do here.

Main Activity call to imageAdapter:

[image: Main Activity call to imageAdapter]

ImageAdapter constructor:

[image: ImageAdapter constructor]

Function throwing the error

[image: Function throwing the error]

Stacktrace

[image: Stacktrace]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Your code doesn't match your error. The `mContext == null` should be entered...

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `this` during field initialization for the Activity because it is before the Android Activity LifeCycle, and thus the Context will be null.

Move `this.imagesAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this)` into `onCreate`